# Google-speadsheet data validation to restrict to Mondays only

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I have a field in Google Sheets I labeled "Week of". I want to restrict user input to a date (mm/dd/yyyy) which is a Monday. I can set "Data validation" -> "criteria" to "Date" but how do I limit it further?

Answer (score 2):

Please try a `Custom formula is` of :

```
=weekday(A1)=2
```

to the relevant column (ie adjust `A` to suit).